# Adding index to a table

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-ctp5

I have a table `Person`: `id, name`

I often have queries like:

```
select * from Person where name Like "%abc%".
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How do I implement this query using code-first 5 (CTP5)
2. How do I add an index on the name column to make data retrieval faster based on name like in the query?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Like operator can be performed with Contains function:

```
var query = from p in context.Persons
            where p.Name.Contains("abc")
            select p;
```

Index must be added by SQL - there is no special construction in EF to create index. You can execute this SQL from DB initialization.

First you must implement custom initializer:

```
public class MyInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyContext>
{
  protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
  {
    context.Database.SqlCommand("CREATE INDEX IX_Person_Name ON Person (Name)");
  }
}
```

Then you must register new initializer:

```
DbDatabase.SetInitializer<MyContext>(new MyInitializer());
```

Comment: I will expect to use `Seed()` for seeding data and I think the sql command should be performed in `DbMigration.Up()`. I try to access dbContext in the `Up()` method but no luck, but I found there is `DbMigration.Sql()`. Seems like in my `Up()`, I can call `this.Sql("CREATE INDEX IX_Person_Name ON Person (Name)")`. am I in a right track?

Comment: @CallMeLaNN: Yes. This question was answered long time prior migrations were released. When using migrations you should place the SQL command to `Up` method in your migration.

Comment: Where to call `SetInitializer`?

Answer (score 2):

in EF 6 you can create indexes like this

```
   Property(t => t.TotalValue)
            .HasColumnAnnotation(
                IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName,
                new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_inventory_import_total_value", 1))
            );
```

Comment: Does it suport multiple columnt?