# Entity Framework Code First - Change Table Column Collation

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-ctp5, ef-code-first

I'm using Entity Framework CTP5 and Code First.  I need to change the Collation for a specific column in SQL Server. I believe the default collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, but I need to change this one column colllation to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS (Case Sensitive).

Is there a way to use ModelBuilder in Code First to change a specific column collation?

BarDev

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Model builder doesn't allow this but you can create custom database initializer and execute `ALTER TABLE` command. The example will be the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040795/adding-index-to-a-table) creating custom index.

Comment: Perfect I did something like this and it seemed to work:

context.Database.SqlCommand("ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN MyColumn VARCHAR(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS  NULL");

Answer (score 3):

Some years later:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().Property(c => c.Name).UseCollation("SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS");
```

Comment: This answer is dependent upon your EF version. OP mentions EF CTP5 for which `UseCollation` does not exist. The method appears to exist in (at least modern versions of) EF Core.