# .NET MVC 3 Code First database collation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-ce, code-first, collation

I'm trying to deploy my .NET MVC3 application without success.
I have a datetime issue I'm not able to fix. Let me try to explain :

I have installed Microsoft visual web developper 2010 in French. My localization in control panel is French. 
When I code first my model and try to deploy my app I can see that my tables are created with SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS collation which means English localization !??! Then I have, of course, a datetime issue with my production database.
How can I change the collation of my SQLserver Compact database in dev to match my production database ? Why EF is creating my tables with english collation ??

Thanks for your help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Code First - Change Table Column Collation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285781/entity-framework-code-first-change-table-column-collation)

Comment: Not a duplicate, linked question is to change collation for a specific column, this relates to changing the default collation for the entire database

Answer (score 2):

Acccording to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174596(v=sql.90).aspx

> All databases that are created without specifying the Windows collation name are assigned Latin1_General, the default collation. Example: Latin1_General_CI_AS. This collation uses the Latin1 General dictionary sorting rules, code page 1252. It is case-insensitive and accent-sensitive.

As EF does not seem to support customizing this, I would suggest, if it's an option for you, to install SQL Server Express and use this instead, as SQL Server Express supports alternative default collations.