# Rename table with Code First in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Does anyone knows if it is possible to *just* rename a database table with `Code First` in `Entity Framework 5`?

I just have simple models and a database initializer, but since my database already contains data I've commented that initializer out. So, I **don't** want to `drop` and `create` a whole new database.

When I add new columns to such a model I use the `Package Manager Console` and run `update-database`. to update my database. Does this also work for renaming tables? Does the `update-database` command automatically knows what the old name was?

I don't have a lot of experience with CF yet and learning new stuff every day. Without CF it's 'easy' to just run an `alter table` command and refresh the dbml file... But with CF? I don't have a clue!

Comment: If you use Table attribute it should work.

Comment: Here is something similar.  Hope this helps.  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285781/entity-framework-code-first-change-table-column-collation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the `update-database` command knows what the old name was... So, in case of data loss warnings, you may choose to apply the `-force` option.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
<Table("TableName")> _
Public Class ClassName
....
```