# Entity Framework Code-first default data in database

Tags: database, entity-framework, initialization, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

How do I handle situations in which I need pre-existing data before the app is started or right after the database is generated. For example, I have a list of countries in which I'd like to load into the database after code-first generates it. How do I do this?

App is structured as follows:

`Repository > Service > WebMVC`

The xml is in the `WebMVC` project.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You create custom initializer, which inherits from `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` or `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` interface. Like:

```
public class EntitiesContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<-YourDbContext->
```

And then you overwrite Seed method like:

```
protected override void Seed(YourDbContext context)
```

Whole example might look like:

```
public class EntitiesContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EntitiesContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(EntitiesContext context)
    {
        List<Role> roles = new List<Role>
        {
            new Role {Id=1, Title="Admin"},
            new Role {Id=2, Title="ProjectManager"},
            new Role {Id=3, Title="Developer"}
        };

        // add data into context and save to db
        foreach (Role r in roles)
        {
            context.Roles.Add(r);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();

    }
}
```

Edit: After setting this up, you have to set up Initializer too, as Ladislav Mrnka mentioned.

```
Database.SetInitializer(new EntitiesContextInitializer());
```

ie.: in Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    Database.SetInitializer(new EntitiesContextInitializer());
}
```

Don't forget to add `using System.Data.Entity;`
.....

Comment: This will only create list of roles. You must add them to the context and save changes.

Comment: @Dampe Can I use the Database.SetInitializer in the webUI project or does it have to be where I create the DbContext?

Comment: @Lol coder: You can add it into Global.asax file into `Application_Start` method. You will need to add Using.System.Data.Entity;

Comment: For some reason it executes the Database.SetInitializer method, but it does not execute the Seed method. I set break points in it and nothing happened.

Comment: I don't know what could be wrong. It works for me. Maybe your database is already filled and you are using `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`. Try to manually delete the database in SQL Management Studio (or tool you use). And run the app again. It should be fired when there is no database prepared.

Comment: Not a bad idea to call `base.Seed()` at the end of this method.

Comment: Small note, you don't need to call `context.SaveChanges();` in `Seed()`, even if you skip `base.Seed()` it saves automatically.

Comment: There is no need to call base.Seed() it does nothing. Also, as Full_Int has said above there is no need to call SaveChanges(). This happens automatically after seeding.

Comment: I guess there were some changes in EF in the 5 years that have passed since this answer was written :) It's nice to see they were cutting unnecessary (always repeating) pieces like context.SaveChanges()

Answer (score 11):

You must create custom database initializer derived for example from `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` and fill data in overriden `Seed` method. Then you must use `Database.SetInitializer` to set your new initializer when application starts. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040795/adding-index-to-a-table) is example (from CTP5) used to create custom index in the database.

Comment: because I can only use the file access code from the web front end, is there a way for me to call the initializer or pass up the data instead?

Comment: You can wrap initialization in custom code and pass data from web app to that code which will in turn pass data to a new instance of your initializer.

Answer (score 1):

For an example see the new MVC / Entity Framework tutorial series at
http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials#Using%20MVC
Both #1 and #4 show initializer classes.