# SQL Server CE with entity framework code first issue

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, code-first, sql-server-ce-4

I want to use code first with SQL Server CE but after run update-database command database file not created. But console show run successfully.
this is my connection string:

```
<add name="AdminTools" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\AdminTools.sdf" />
```

please help

Comment: Are you seeding the database? Using something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655841/entity-framework-code-first-default-data-in-database

Comment: Yes I seed database and in console print that database create successfully and seeding is OK but I don't see database file.

Comment: Strange because it should exist on the App_Data folder.

Comment: This is windows library project. I search for **AdminTools.sdf** in bin and 
entire solution folder but I don't see database file.