# How do display top 5 products from specific category

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework, select, nopcommerce

I want to fetch top 5 most popular product under specific category say **computer**.

This is my class file:

```
  public partial class Category {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public int ParentCategoryId { get; set; } //reference to Id 
       public ICollection<Category> _subcategories;
  } 

  public partial class ProductCategory {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public int ProductId { get; set; }
       public int CategoryId { get; set; }
       public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
       public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
  }

 public partial class Product {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }                     
       public int ProductViewcount { get; set; }//indicated how many times product has been viewed means most popular product.
 }
```

Here a sample fiddle which contain records: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/20cba

Final output:

ProductId   ProductName

1             hp

2             compaq

3             lenovo

Here problem  is **Computer** is my main **category** and **laptop is child category** of **Computer** so when i say get top 5 Product of computer i want to retrieve child category records also like in fiddle i want to get all records of child category that is **Laptop**

I know this that I have to perform order by on **ProductViewCount** and **get top 5 products**.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you need recursive SQL select or LINQ expression? You can't do it with LINQ, but you can do it with SQL. Use [common table expressions, CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx). The example D shows how to do it.

Comment: oh i thought if anybody post solution in the form of sql query then i would get idea from that sql query and write linq query from that sql query.why this is not possible with linq???

Comment: Downvoters please give me your reason to downvote??

Comment: You can't do it as a one shot LINQ query without having a CTE. What you can do is create the CTE as a SQL View and then query that for what you want.

Comment: @IronMan84:can you please post your CTE sql Query because i dont know what is CTE and i havent use CTE.so please just post your CTE query and check in Fiddle for the correct output

Comment: @MarkShevchenko:can you please post CTE Sql Query because i havent use CTE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's define what we need. We need a table (view) with these fields: `ProductId`, `ProductName`, `ProductViewCount`, and `RootCategoryId`.

Imagine, the `Category` table has `RootCategoryId` field already. Then we can use this query to receive the result:

```
SELECT P.Id AS 'ProductId', P.Name AS 'ProductName', PVC.ProductViewCount, C.RootCategoryId
FROM Category C
  INNER JOIN ProductCategory PC ON PC.CategoryId = C.Id
  INNER JOIN Product P ON PC.ProductId = P.Id
  INNER JOIN ProductViewCount PVC ON P.Id = PVC.ProductId
```

Unfortunately the `Category` table hasn't necessary fields. So we need a table (instead of `Category`) with fields `CategoryId` and `RootCategoryId`.

For top categories `CategoryId` and `RootCategoryId` are the same:

```
SELECT Id AS 'CategoryId', Id AS 'RootCategoryId'
FROM Category
WHERE ParentCategoryId = 0
```

For descendant categories `CategoryId` is the `Id`, and `RootCategoryId` is the same as the parent. So we can write CTE:

```
WITH RecursiveCategory(CategoryId, RootCategoryId)
AS
(
    SELECT Id AS 'CategoryId', Id AS 'RootCategoryId'
    FROM Category
    WHERE ParentCategoryId = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C.Id AS 'CategoryId', RC.RootCategoryId
    FROM Category C
        INNER JOIN RecursiveCategory RC ON C.ParentCategoryId = RC.CategoryId
)
. . .
```

Now let's put the pieces together. We need a VIEW:

```
CREATE VIEW ProductWithRootCategory
AS
WITH RecursiveCategory(CategoryId, RootCategoryId)
AS
(
    SELECT Id AS 'CategoryId', Id AS 'RootCategoryId'
    FROM Category
    WHERE ParentCategoryId = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C.Id AS 'CategoryId', RC.RootCategoryId
    FROM Category C
        INNER JOIN RecursiveCategory RC ON C.ParentCategoryId = RC.CategoryId
)
SELECT P.Id AS 'ProductId', P.Name AS 'ProductName', PVC.ProductViewCount, RC.RootCategoryId
FROM RecursiveCategory RC
  INNER JOIN ProductCategory PC ON PC.CategoryId = RC.CategoryId
  INNER JOIN Product P ON PC.ProductId = P.Id
  INNER JOIN ProductViewCount PVC ON P.Id = PVC.ProductId
```

Now you can add the view to EF and use:

```
int rootCategoryId = 1; // Is's Computers
var productsInRootCategory = ProductWithRootCategory.Where(pwrc => pwrc.RootCategoryId == rootCategoryId);
var top5Products = productsInRootCategory.OrderBy(pwrc => pwrc.ProductViewCount).Take(5);
```

Comment: for checking purpose that it is returning correct list of products or not  i want to do this checking in your query.

Comment: right now i want to hardcode this ParentCategorName parameter and directly specify in your query to check whether this View is working or not

Comment: I rewrote my answer. Now there's no `ParentCategoryName`, the new VIEW is called `ProductWithRootCategory`.

Comment: sir the condition you are checking on server side i want to check that condition in my query only.i will pass that CategoryId from server as a parameter to this view.so checking will be done on View part only and not on server side

Comment: A view is not a stored procedure, it has no parameters. So you should use `ProductWithRootCategory` in your LINQ query. At the end of my answer there is an example of LINQ expression.

Comment: i am using Entity Framework code first.so directly i can use like this as you have specified?

Comment: sorry i was not knowing that we cannot pass parameter to view.sorry sir

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889905/how-do-i-define-a-database-view-using-entity-framework-4-code-first

Comment: i cant uppvote your ans which i want to upvote because i dont have 15 reputation

Comment: Damn genius sir.very very nice.this query is a sign of genius sir.thank you so much sir.really thank you