# Is there an attribute like [Table()] to create a class that maps to a view in EF Code First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I am working with Entity Framework Code First, and am trying to create a class that will map to a View. I know how to do it for a table, like below:

```
[Table("FIL002")]
public class FIL002
{  
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Int64 Payer_Number { get; set; }
    public string Payer_Name { get; set; }
}
```

However, I could not find an attribute for View (Like `[Table(...)]`. Is there one?

Answer (score 0):

Views are queried in the exact same way as tables. Therefore, just use `[Table()]` as usual.

This does not make the associated DB collection read-only though, so you have to make sure not to try to save any of the objects you get out of it (unless your view is writable of course).

Comment: How does EF however know it is a view? I do not want the code to allow changes to an instance of this object (will SaveChanges be available ?)

Comment: You have to create the view first. Or you can ignore the SQL view and use LINQ

Comment: I don't think EF supports read-only collections in the first place. If you want to make absolutely sure no writes will go through even if somebody tries to do so, you could override `SaveChanges` and manually check if any entities which are supposed to be read only have been changed.

Comment: @raminsh - If you make the view read-only, by removing insert/update/delete permissions from the view object, then EF can't update it.. exceptions will get thrown if someone tries.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct approach [as explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5890057/1042934) in code-first but you can you DbContext to send [raw SQL](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx) ['create view'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) command like this :

```
public class MyInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyContext>
{
  protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
  {
    query = "CREATE VIEW [ schema_name . ] view_name [ (column [ ,...n ] ) ] 
            [ WITH <view_attribute> [ ,...n ] ] 
            AS select_statement 
             [ WITH CHECK OPTION ] 
             [ ; ]

            <view_attribute> ::= 
            {
                [ ENCRYPTION ]
                [ SCHEMABINDING ]
                [ VIEW_METADATA ]     
            } ";

    context.Database.SqlCommand(query);
  }
}
```