# Creating Indexes via Data Annotations with EF 5

Tags: entity-framework-5, code-first

I am using EF5 and code first to create database. I have one string field and would like to put Index(non-unique) on it. Is it possible to create Index using Data Annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF doesn't have a special way to create indices, you need to revert to an old style SQL statement.

you can use the seed method to do this

```
protected override void Seed(EntityMappingContext context)
{
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE INDEX IX_NAME ON TABLE (COLUMN)");
}
```

as described here: [Adding index to a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040795/adding-index-to-a-table)

Comment: You can seed either by using a custom initialiser or by using migrations to do the same

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Code Migrations, you could modify a migration ('Up' method) to add an index to a new table:
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.tablename",
        c => {...})
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.PrimaryKeyColumn)
        .Index(t => t.IndexColumn);

...or, if you're adding an index to an existing table, use:
    CreateIndex("dbo.tablename", t => t.IndexColumn)

Don't forget to delete the index when downgrading the db ('Down' method)
    DropIndex(...)